# How to do string formatting in BetterC mode?

Tags: d

I'd like to use something like the "Concepts" package from Atila Neves.

I implemented the check of an object against a type signature myself in a simple naive way. I can check `struct` objects against interfaces which I define within compile-time-evaluated delegate blocks to make them work with BetterC. I only used compile-time function evaluation with `enum`s which receive return values of executed delegate code blocks.

Now I faced problems with `std.format.format` which uses **TypeInfo** for `%s` formatters which gives errors when compiling in BetterC. For code generation I'd like to use token strings because they have syntax highlighting. But proper usage of them requires string interpolation or string formatting. `core.stdc.stdio.snprintf` is no alternative because CTFE can only interprete D source code.

This is not technically a problem. I can just turn token strings into WYSIWYG strings.

But I wonder why I can't use it. The official documentation says, compile-time features are unrestricted for BetterC (I assume this includes **TypeInfo**). Either it is plain wrong or I am doing it wrong.

```cpp
template implementsType(alias symbol, type)
    if (isAbstractClass!type)
{
    enum implementsType = mixin(implementsTypeExpr);
    
    enum implementsTypeExpr =
    {
        import std.format : format;
        auto result = "";
        static foreach(memberName; __traits(allMembers, type))
        {
            result ~= format(
                q{__traits(compiles, __traits(getMember, symbol, "%1$s")) && }~
                q{covariantSignature!(__traits(getMember, symbol, "%1$s"), __traits(getMember, type, "%1$s")) && }
                    , memberName);
        }
        return (result.length >= 3)? result[0 .. $-3] : result;
    }();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TypeInfo` are [not available](https://dlang.org/spec/betterc.html#consequences) with BetterC.

There's a [bc-string](https://code.dlang.org/packages/bc-string) dub package that provides a limited string formatter that will work in BetterC.

Comment: Now it would be nice to know, why `TypeInfo` is not available in CTFE because the documentation says, that CTFE features for BetterC are unrestricted.